# How to get share (view) count of current page URL from StumbleUpon (use jQuery.getJSON)?

Tags: jquery, json, stumbleupon

I try to get share (view) count of URL from StumbleUpon on my site (I use this page in [official API](http://help.stumbleupon.com/customer/portal/articles/665227-badges) for understanding JSON response):

```
$.getJSON('http://www.stumbleupon.com/services/1.01/badge.getinfo?url=' + encodeURIComponent(location.href) + '&callback=?', function(response) {
  console.log(response.result.views);
});
```

Also I try this code:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.stumbleupon.com/services/1.01/badge.getinfo?url=' + encodeURIComponent(location.href) + '&callback=?', function(response) {
  var getResult = 'result';
  for (var getResult in response) {
    if (response.hasOwnProperty(getResult)) {
      var count = response.getResult.views;
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(count);
});
```

But `Google Chrome` console always show me this error message:

```
badge.getinfo?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2F&callback=jQuery11120638845409732312_14430823…:1 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

If I try this link `http://www.stumbleupon.com/services/1.01/badge.getinfo?url=http://www.treehugger.com` (for example) in browser, I get this response:

```
{
    "result": {
        "url": "http:\/\/www.treehugger.com\/",
        "in_index": true,
        "publicid": "1tin26",
        "views": 109703,
        "title": "TreeHugger",
        "thumbnail": "http:\/\/cdn.stumble-upon.com\/mthumb\/428\/925428.jpg",
        "thumbnail_b": "http:\/\/cdn.stumble-upon.com\/bthumb\/428\/925428.jpg",
        "submit_link": "http:\/\/www.www.stumbleupon.com\/submit?url=http:\/\/www.treehugger.com\/",
        "badge_link": "http:\/\/www.www.stumbleupon.com\/badge?url=http:\/\/www.treehugger.com\/",
        "info_link": "http:\/\/www.www.stumbleupon.com\/url\/www.treehugger.com\/"
    },
    "timestamp": 1289496144,
    "success": true
}
```

Any ideas? Help me please, if you can!

Comment: This problem is still relevant for me.. Help pls!

Comment: Ask this on official forums https://getsatisfaction.com/stumbleupon_help_center/topics/how-to-get-share-view-count-of-current-page-url-from-stumbleupon-use-jquery-getjson

Comment: I also have the same issue getting the `timestamp` using josnp. did you figure it out?